# KO-JS Memory leak with lots of observables single page app

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, memory-leaks

I have noticed that there seems to be a memory leak when using ko js observables (or perhaps I'm doing something wrong) on a single page app using ko components.

Basically I get lots of data from an ajax call to a REST API (array of ~2000 items). Storing these locally and converting to observables for manipulation/viewing. When the user navigates away to another page, the amount of memory remains the same. Then, when navigating back to that page, the data is reloaded and stored in memory. Repeat that process and eventually the browser crashes. Watching the Task Manager on chrome I can see this memory continus to escalate. Here's a simple version that I'm seeing the same results.

```
function VM(params) {
    this.data = ko.observableArray();    
    //populate the data so it looks similar to what is given by the server
    var arr = []
    //i made it 10k since these are simple objects and I want to memory being used to be somewhat substantial to mimic the real data.
    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) { 
      arr.push({
          val1: i,
          val2: i,
          val3: i,
          val4: i,
          val5: i,
          val6: i,
          val7: i,
          val8: i,
          val9: i,
          val10: i
      });
  }
  self.data(arr.map(function (x) {
      return new dataObj(x);
  }))
}
var dataObj = function (data) {
  //using ko.mapping.fromJS or separating them out has the same results:
  //option 1:
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
  //option 2:
  this.val1 = ko.observable(data.val1)
  this.val2 = ko.observable(data.val2)
     //etc.
}
```

I noticed that there's a function when the component is deconstructed:

```
VM.prototype.dispose = function() {};
```

I'm not sure what (if any) I can call in that function to 'clear' the memory.  If any additional info is required to help me out lmk. I've been banging my head on this for several days now :(

Any thoughts on fixing this? Am I doing something incorrect here?

Comment: When you say "the user navigates away to another page", do you mean in the context of a *single page app*? Or are you saving stuff to `localStorage`?

Comment: I mean when they navigate to another 'page' on my app. Clicking on any <a>link</a>. When they navigate to another page outside of my app (e.g. google.com), everything is cleared out as expected.

Comment: How do you use your _VM_ (is it simply view model for component or you create a new instance of it manually)? Does your component ever destroyed (method VM.prototype.dispose is called)? Have you tried to use [Chrome's Heap Snapshot](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/heap-snapshots) for analyze?

Comment: Do you use _ko.computed()_ or _observable.subscribe()_ in your _dataObj_?